# Extract substrings between two different delimiters in SAS

Tags: sas, substring, extract

Using SAS, trying to extract data between these two delimiters `[`,`]`
for two cases: Beginning with `#CB` or `CR:`

Input data:

```
Scenario,Order_ID,Review
1,1234,<Order No. 10><Remark>Food was good</Remark><UserID>7890</UserID><Filter>[#CB:Customer happy with service]</Filter><Rating>5</Rating>
2,1235,<Rating>Five</Rating><Order No. 17><UserID>7880</UserID><Filter>[#CB:Customer had a good time]</Filter><Remark>Food was good</Remark><Additional>Service up to par</Additional><Remark>[#CB:Customer will return again]</Remark><End>Thats all</End>
3,1236,<Start>We shall begin</Start><Intro>[CR:Fine Dining Experience]</Intro><Rating>Three</Rating><Order No. 12><Filter>[#CB:Food was well prepared]</Filter><Remark>Food was good</Remark><Additional>Ambiance was lively</Additional><Remark>[CR:Hygine was maintained]</Remark><End>Could be better</End><UserID>7880</UserID>
```

Data wanted:

```
Scenario,Order_ID,Review1,Review2,Review3,Review4
1,1234,#CB:Customer happy with service,,,
2,1235,#CB:Customer had a good time,#CB:Customer will return again,,
3,1236,CR:Fine Dining Experience,#CB:Food was well prepared,CR:Hygine was maintained,
```

Comment: This definitely looks like a job for regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
data have;
infile cards4 dlm=",";
length Scenario Order_ID 8 Review $ 1024;
input Scenario Order_ID Review : $ char1024.;
cards4;
1,1234,<Order No. 10><Remark>Food was good</Remark><UserID>7890</UserID><Filter>[#CB:Customer happy with service]</Filter><Rating>5</Rating> 
2,1235,<Rating>Five</Rating><Order No. 17><UserID>7880</UserID><Filter>[#CB:Customer had a good time]</Filter><Remark>Food was good</Remark><Additional>Service up to par</Additional><Remark>[#CB:Customer will return again]</Remark><End>Thats all</End> 
3,1236,<Start>We shall begin</Start><Intro>[CR:Fine Dining Experience]</Intro><Rating>Three</Rating><Order No. 12><Filter>[#CB:Food was well prepared]</Filter><Remark>Food was good</Remark><Additional>Ambiance was lively</Additional><Remark>[CR:Hygine was maintained]</Remark><End>Could be better</End><UserID>7880</UserID> 
;;;;
run;
proc print;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array R[*] $ 256 Review1 Review2 Review3 Review4;

  do i=1 to dim(R);
    R[i] = scan(scan(strip(Review) !! "[ ]", i, "]"), -1, "[", "R");
  end;

  output;
  drop Review i;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

and take a look at the [`SCAN()` function](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0jshdjy2z9zdzn1h7k90u99lyq6.htm) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

With regex function `prxparse()` and `prxnext()`, you can define, match and capture pattern strings precisely.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array R[*] $ 1024 Review1 Review2 Review3 Review4;

  pat=prxparse('/\[(?:#CB|CR:).*?\]/');
  start=1;
  end=length(review);
  call prxnext(pat, start, end, review, pos, len);
  if len>0 then do i=1 by 1 while(pos>0);
    R[i]=substr(review, pos+1, len-2);
    call prxnext(pat, start, end, review, pos, len);
  end;
  keep Scenario Order_ID Review1 Review2 Review3 Review4;
run;
```

1. Use `prxparse()` function to define the pattern of your target string: surround with `[` and `]`, in the brackets, beginning with `#CB` or `CR:` and following by any characters but `]`.
2. Use `call prxnext()` to match next pattern, once it matches something, the position and length of which it matches will be return to `pos` and `len`.
3. Use `substr()` to extract target string from source string, with `pos+1` and `len+2`, because brackets `[` and `]` on the both sides should be removed.
4. Loop step 2 and step 3, while `len` is greater than 0, which means step 2 matches something.